# C# using a timer within another timer?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm programming a tetris game. So far I have implemented a timer with a very short interval of around 50 ms. Every tick the current falling tetromino gets moved one position in the game matrix downwards. Then the game checks if there is a collision, if so the tetromino gets marked as "landed" and new tetromino is spawned.

No I have the problem that I want to give the player the chance to move the tetromino to the left or right for let's say 0.5 seconds after it landed to have the possibility to move the tetromino underneath an overhanging already landed tetromino.

But with my current code I have the problem that as soon as there is a collision detected the timer continues and spawns the next tetromino. My idea now was to try to implement a second timer that gets activated for 0.5 seconds everytime a collision is detected to allow for additional keyboard input bevore the main timer continues. So basically pausing the main timer for 0.5 seconds and allow the program to detect keyboard input during that time and then continue with the main timer.

Everything I tried so far didn't really work. It seems like the first timer always continues running while I have a second timer active.

This is how my first timer looks like:

```
private void TimerBrick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetGameBoard(jaggedTetrisBricks[rnd-1][rotation], _brickX, _brickY, xLengthBrick, yLengthBrick);
            _brickX++;
            CollisionCheck(jaggedTetrisBricks[rnd - 1][rotation], _brickX, _brickY, xLengthBrick, yLengthBrick);
            LineCheck();

            Invalidate();
        }
```

Now I somehow need to implement inside my `CollisionCheck()` method a way to wait for 0.5 seconds before the code continues with `LineCheck()`.

Or is there another way that I'm not seeing right now?

Comment: You can use `Thread.Sleep(time)`, but maybe this will pause the whole program, if that's the case you could use a Task for the teromino, but that will cause other issues you'll have to adress.

Comment: How about implementing a state driven system in your main timer tick - normal state is "BrickFalling", once you detect a collision you change state to "MoveSideways" which lasts for 10 ticks, then you create a new brick & return to "BrickFalling". Inside the timer tick event, just use an if or switch. It will then be easy to add further state if you want to.

Comment: What @PaulF suggests is the [usual approach in games](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html). You could also make 0.5 seconds a default interval of your game loop, so other kinds of processing will be available during the 'Falling' state.

Comment: @PaulIF I like the idea. But how can I say within my 'TimerBrick_Tick' event that I want to do something for 10 ticks only and then switch back to something else?

Comment: I made it work, thanks!

Comment: :) - you just beat me to posting my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my previous comment - here is a bit of pseudo-code :

```
enum GameState
{
    Starting,
    CreateBrick,
    BrickFalling,
    MoveSideways
}

private GameState curState = Starting;
private ushort ctSideways;

private void TimerBrick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (curState)
    {
        case Starting:
            InitialiseGame();
            curState = CreateBrick;
            break;

        case CreateBrick:
            CreateNewBrick();
            curState = BrickFalling;
            break;

        case BrickFalling:
            .....
            .....
            if (CollisionCheck())
            {
                ctSideways = 0;
                curState = MoveSideways;
            }
            break;

        case MoveSideways:
            .....
            .....
            ctSidways++;
            if (ctSideways == 10)
                curState = CreateBrick;
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks I had a similar approach with a variable counting up to change the state when the variable reaches a certain value ;)